# geoserver kml reflector in cesium viewer

Tags: geoserver, wms, kml, cesium

Is there any way to use the geoserver kml reflector in cesium viewer? I have millions of features with height value. The geoserver kml reflector works in google earths, but not in cesium.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: It works in GE. The kml contains a wms link so it's loading pictires. In a closely zoom level it renders kml vectors (a few 100). In cesium I added a this type of kml, but nothings happening... no errors, no features..

Comment: http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/google_earth/reflector.html This is what I would like to see to work in cesium. If I add this kind of kml to cesium nothing happening.

Comment: Is your geoserver instance returning an Access-Control-Origin-Allow header?

Answer (score 3):

I have it working on a project I'm currently switching from Google Earth to Cesium.  We've found that the crucial variable is `mode=download` because Cesium doesn't seem able to handle `mode=refresh` whether it comes from the KML reflector or the full WMS interface.  I *think* this is because `mode=download` links behave like links to a static file, while `mode=refresh` relies on the `NetworkLink` construct that is specific to Google Earth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, next week I'll try to check it. So how is this work? Will it download all the features? I have a couple of hundred thousand of features and it would be great if it renders in wms in high zoom levels and render the features as kml in low zoom level (the map window contains a couple of hundreds in this case)

Comment: We've had to implement two things in our client-side JavaScript that we used to get for free from Google Earth & Geoserver:

1) Unfortunately when using `mode=download` you have to specify whether Geoserver will give you vector or raster data. So our own code now decides which to request based on the area in the viewport and a parameter that we hand-code for each layer.

2) We listen for Cesium moveEnd events and request the layer again each time the viewport has changed, with a new bbox.

Comment: Getting these things basically working wasn't too difficult, but there's a lot of challenge & subtlety to making the interaction feel good.  In particular we've had to invest a lot of time into tweaking where the threshold between vector and raster is, and when the refresh should really fire.

Comment: Is this something what you could show me on a working sample? At the moment I have no clue where should I start.

Comment: Not yet, but I should soon - it's work in progress.  Here's the algorithm

1. Get the bounding box of the current view (let me know if you're also stuck with this - I actually have working code I can share for this part).
2. Estimate the size of the area in view.
3. Compare that to a score we set manually for each data layer (we're using the kmscore attribute that we used to pass to Geoserver).
4. Based on the relationship between 2 & 3, either request the layer from Geoserver with `format=kml` (to get vectors) or `format=image/png`

Comment: I would start by hard-coding a request as vectors and one as image, and then work on the logic to choose which to use.

Answer (score 0):

Geoserver kml reflector works fine in Cesium.

...

```
    var optionsKML = {

    camera : viewer.scene.camera,

    canvas : viewer.scene.canvas,

    clampToGround: true

    };

    pk = viewer.dataSources.add(Cesium.KmlDataSource.load('http://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx/geoserver/wms/kml?layers=layername', optionsKML));
```

...

KML data use styling from SLD.

Also set:

1. In Cesium set infBox to true:

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {

...

```
infoBox : true,
```

...

});

2. Set "[KML placemarks](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/googleearth/tutorials/kmlplacemark/index.html)", title.ftl( for labels) and description.ftl ( if you want to display attrib data when clicked on kml entity in Cesium ).